# Translation of Annual and Monthly pricing as "mo" and "yr"

Tags: accessibility, internationalisation, localization, pricing

I'm curious if anyone knows if abbreviating monthly and annual pricing as "../mo" and "../yr" will translate into all other languages? For example, if I display pricing to users as "$220/yr" or "18.33/mo"

Furthermore, I'm wondering if the "/mo" and "/yr" abbreviation is accessible for screen readers?
I've seen Apple do this on their website but they use aria-hidden="true" on this portion of the text.

Comment: What do you mean "translate into all other languages"? Are you using an automated translation utility or something, or are you asking if non-English speakers would know what that means?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, as a native Spanish speaker I can tell you the words are completely different year=año, month=mes, since they are short there is not really an abbreviation. Other languages haver their own words/abbreviations too.

That being said, you will only need to worry about it if you are actually translating the whole site to other languages and you want to keep consistency; to that purpose in some cases you will also need to change the currency sign, not every body uses $. If you are curious you can take a look to the apple site you mention and append a country suffix to see how it's handled

Mexico:
https://www.apple.com/mx/

Germany
https://www.apple.com/de

just to list a couple, good luck!